# Angular JS- One <input> Field accepts two different types of data (coordinate string or address string)

Tags: angular, validation, input

Brand new to Angular and am just starting to flesh out an input box that accepts either coordinates or user's address as a string based on the click of an icon. The getRequest() method in the .ts file needs to determine what kind of string the user's input is - in order to validate and set up the API request properly.  I am trying to add a dynamic [ngClass] with the click of the icon but cannot really get to the class name from the .ts file. How do I access the dynamic class name of the  element? I am hoping if  I can check what class the input element is set at I will know what data to expect.  Or should I be tackling this differently?  Thanks.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="locationOptions home" 
   (click)="showHomeCoords=!showHomeCoords; 
            homeAddressFromField.value=null;">

    <i #homeIcon class="material-icons" *ngIf="!showHomeCoords">home</i>
    <i #homeCrosshairIcon class="material-icons" *ngIf="showHomeCoords">my_location</i>
</div>

  <mat-form-field formGroup='homeForm' name="myHome" class="half-width" appearance="outline" flex>

    <mat-label>Home Address</mat-label>
      <input type="text"
             formControlName="homeInput"
             [ngClass]="showHomeCoords ? 'coords' : 'address'"
             matInput placeholder={{changeHomePlaceHolder()}} 
             #homeAddressFromField 
              required>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**.TS**

```
@ViewChild('homeAddressFromField') homeAddressFromField : ElementRef; 

 detectCoordinateOrAddress(locationEntered:any){

   let homeField = this.homeAddressFromField.nativeElement;

   let a1: any;

  if(homeField.querySelectorAll('.coords'){

       a1 = this.isThisInputCoordinateGood(locationEntered)

  }else{

       a1 = parseAddress.parseLocation(locationEntered)

  }

  return a1;

 };


getRequest(home:any){

  let h = this.detectCoordinateOrAddress(home);

  this.setRequest(h);

  this.returnInfo(this.request);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok my suggestion is in your input field, use a variable like this

```
      <input type="text"
         formControlName="homeInput"
         [ngClass]="homeCoordinates"
         matInput placeholder={{changeHomePlaceHolder()}} 
         #homeAddressFromField 
          required>
```

and set the variable to the correct class name inside your .ts function.

Or if you really want to use the way you mentioned, set the variable showHomeCoords to true / false from inside your .ts function